# find all file extension recursively from directory and copy all extension files to single directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, regular-expression, recursive

I have directory with sub-dir where it has multiple extensions file. I would like to copy all ext files to single directory "scan". Tried running following cmd but doesnt work out:

```
find . -name \*.py -o -name \*.sql -o -name \*.conf -o -name \*.csv -exec cp {} scan/ \;
```

It just take those specific ext but copy only last ext ie .csv files to "scan" folder

Tried running below command, but it just gives what all ext. files  have:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's|.*\.||' | sort -u
conf
coveragerc
css
csv
eot
etlconf
gitignore
hql
html
idx
ini
js
json
log
map
md
pack
pdf
py
sample
sh
sql
svg
ttf
txt
woff
woff2
```

i would like to run a command that will search all extn files that i have and copy to the scan folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop is a less verbose:

```bsh
$ shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
$ for i in **/*.{sql,conf,py,csv}; do 
    cp "$i" "scan/$(basename "$i")"
  done
```